# Cannot Control Volume in TVTime

Tags: tvtime

I just installed TVTime, but I cannot move the Volume value from 0, no matter if I use the left/right keys on the arrow-pad. I edited the tvtime.xml's AudioBoost value to 1, but that did not change anything. Is there a way to configure TVTime to allow for the value to be adjusted?

**EDIT**: I am using a hauppauge tv-tuner card as well.

Answer (score 3):

try launching tvtime from terminal

```
tvtime --mixer=hw:0/Line
```

if that works, proceed editing configuration file

```
sudo gedit /etc/tvtime/tvtime.xml
```

and find the line

```
<option name="MixerDevice" value="default/Line"/>
```

and replace it with

```
<option name="MixerDevice" value="hw:0/Line"/>
```

pd: excuse my English

Answer (score 2):

This makes the voulme slide goes up and down, but sound can still be missing.

Try:

cat /proc/asound/cards

Then the result will be something like:

0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                      HDA Intel at xxxxxxxxxxxx
 1 [EasyALSA1      ]: easycapdc60 - easycap_alsa
                      easycap_alsa

Then just type (if your video is the 0 change video1 to video0):

tvtime-configure --device=/dev/video1 --mixer=/proc/asound/EasyALSA1:monitor

Then type:

tvtime -v

and when the key + and - is pressed the slide will go up and down, if still no sound is because the mixer=device:channel is for OSS, the ALSA way is device/channel but I do not know yet what is the equivalent, because the path needs / and also the separator between device and channel.